# For non-uniformly sampled data, how to decide whether interpolation or Lomb-Scargle periodogram is better?

Tags: nonuniform

When handling non-uniformly sampled data, we can use one of the following methods to estimate the frequency spectrum:

1. Interpolation in time/space domain, then go for classical periodogram OR
2. Use Lomb-Scargle periodgram

So my question is how do we decide when to choose method 1 and when to go with method 2?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any insights in the meantime?