# Lomb-Scargle or Periodogram for non-uniformly sampled data

Tags: sampling, power-spectral-density, nonuniform, sparse-fourier-transform

I have non-uniformly sampled data and I'm trying to look at its Power Spectral Density (PSD).
For that, I looked at the Periodogram PSD estimate of an interpolated (with uniform sampling period) version of my data and compared it to the Lomb-Scargle PSD estimate of my original data.

[image]

[image]

I'm surprised to see that the resulting PSDs are different, especially for high frequencies, given that the interpolated data seems to follow quite well the original data. Now, I'm not sure which one should I trust!

I would appreciate it if anyone can explain why this difference and which one to use.

P.S: I found this related question [For non-uniformly sampled data, how to decide whether interpolation or Lomb-Scargle periodogram is better?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/56310/28774) but no answers/comments were given.

Comment: How did you interpolate? Is the underlying signal bandlimited?

Comment: @Gillespie, interpolated using 'interp1' matlab function with the linear method.
I don't have a clear idea on the spectrum of the underlying signal, that's exactly why I'm trying to look at the PSD.

Comment: @Gillespie Also, this particular data I included is supposed to contain only noise.

Comment: Given that it's not bandlimited, there's no telling how aliased the signal was in the sampling process. And interpolation of nonuniformly sampled signals is complicated even when they are bandlimited: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84232/55647. So I would say it's hard (impossible?) to tell which PSD is more accurate.

Comment: @Gillespie, Does this mean that we can't say, for sure, that Lomb-Scargle PSD gives a more accurate PSD, although it's supposed to be adequate for dealing with nonuniform sampling.

Comment: Non-zero aliasing isn't a dealbreaker for empirical methods. Your question is answerable.

Comment: Also the linked question isn't "related" but a duplicate. You can set this question apart by including data/code. I'm for one unsure there's a meaningful difference in the plots since they are logscaled and that is subject to the transformation procedure, which for one isn't independent of input scaling, "input" being the output of PSD & Lomb-Scargle. I also see little high frequency content in the time-domain waveform, which justifies greater estimator uncertainty there.